# the blue whale calf gains 200 pounds per day- amazing biotransformation

Tags: zoology

MY main research topic is TIME in relation to biology the blue whale calf CONVERTING mothers milk to fuctional bio-mass(up to 200 pounds/day) IS amazing-if this secret could be uncovered and used in relation to crops/livestock it woud be a game changer QUESTION does anyone have knowledge of ANY research pertaining to this  (delta time-biomass accumulation/growth genetics)?

Answer (score 1):

> MY main research topic is TIME in relation to biology the blue whale calf CONVERTING mothers milk to fuctional bio-mass(up to 200 pounds/day) IS amazing-if this secret could be uncovered

Wikipedia says they weigh 40,000 lbs when they finish nursing, so I think the "secret" is to be really, really large.  Relative to body mass, gaining 200 pounds a day is actually very slow for a mammal.  Human babies grow faster than that.

Comment: It’s the “relative” bit that is important here.

Comment: you need to slow down a bit and REALLY think  about this as a biologist (are you one?)the mothers milk goes into the calf gets  broken down then absorbed the calf is taking in "raw material"and digesting it and gaining weight of 200 lbs  per day(BIOTRANSFORMATION  from mixed protiens+sugars [lactose)per day the "raw material"  is transformed to bio active physiological cells YOU DON'T think this is amazing in a big picture stem cell world? how much does a human leg weigh?(axolotl/starfish/worms/lizard tails)20  lbs?  TAKE the PROOF of the blue whale calf and a human leg could be re-grown 1DAY

Comment: @hyperchronos12 Asking people's opinions is offtopic here.  Stick to biology questions.

Comment: your community lacks scientific imagination and fails to project into the future---which is in some way good i will be the one going to sweden and stand on the carpet

Comment: i am not "asking for opinions" i am attempting to make clear the original question of  TIME vs-BIOMASS  accumulation, i used the blue whale calf as a proof of the possible   hopefully the readers have an understanding of genetic engineering/pluripotent stem cells/axolotl(ability to regrow severed limbs THE genetics that enable the blue whale calf is my interest-and the transfer  of such we must have an imagination quality in science FIND proofs first axolotl  CAN REGROW LIMBS(concept proof)   blue whale calf gains 200 lbs/day(concept proof) genetic engineering to regrow limbs  NOT PROVEN/YET

Comment: @hyperchronos12 The developmental genetics of mammals is an active area of research.  If that is what you're interested in knowing about, narrow down your inquiry to some specific questions and then post them.

Comment: master question  # 1 have the blue whale    "growth genes been isolated and cloned" ?-QUESTION #1(a)--  have the genes for the stomach/intestines/liver been elucidated that enable these systems to up-take massive amounts of proteins/fats/sugars in a short period of time-? Q #1(b)[bio physics]  is this massive conversion of raw food to bio active cells, exothermic-for which a water borne creature could only withstand?